# how i can know when my Windows service is not working

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have a windows service and i want to know when it is not working not every xx minutes or so but when it stopped

i have this method

```
 public string ServiceStatus()
          {
                switch (_service.Status)
                {
                     case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                          return "Running";
                     case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                          return "Stopped";
                     case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
                          return "Paused";
                     case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
                          return "Stopping";
                     case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
                          return "Starting";
                     default:
                          return "Status Changing";
                }

          }
```

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the Stop, etc. events. For example, to know when you are being "stopped":

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
  // Let yourself know the service has been stopped
}
```

Check out [ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

When the service is stopped, the corresponding OnStop method of the service is called. Inside this function you could write to some event log, or send a message to a message queue.

The code that needs to know whether or not the service is running, that code will have to poll this shared source to know WHEN the service stopped.

That said, if you could elaborate on your question, we could help you better. Information like, what is the code that needs to be informed about the service stopping? If its a web app, the service can make a http call during its OnStop.

Generally, its preferred to make the OnStop exit as soon as possible. If the code inside the OnStop takes too long, Windows might declare the service unresponsive and cause an inproper shutdown.